# Insert a row and delete rows in dataframes in a dictionary using pandas

Tags: pandas, date, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing multiple dataframes, and my dataframes (examples df1 and df2) have the same structure the key to each dataframe in my dict is the id presents in the dataframe (so 'AA' for df1).

I have a data frame (data_extract), not in the dictionary, I would like to add the date in that dataframe to the dataframe in the dictionary with the same id and then add a value and then delete all the dates before the one in data_extract. At the end I want something like df1_bis and df2_bis.

I was thinking about using concat but I'm not sure it is the best idea because in my script I need to delete some rows and I thought modifying each dataframe was more efficient and logical. For the dates I thought about using the calendar day but then again I don't know if it's a good idea and how to use it.

```
a = pd.concat(mydict.values(), ignore_index=True)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['AA', 'AA','AA', 'AA','AA'],
                    'date' : ['01/01/2015', '07/01/2015','19/01/2015', '01/02/2015','08/02/2015'],
                    'value' :  [7,9,1,6,7],
                    'date_y' : [1,7,19,32,39]
                            })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['BB', 'BB','BB', 'BB','BB'],
                    'date' : ['09/01/2015', '17/01/2015','19/02/2015', '01/03/2015','08/03/2015'],
                    'value' :  [8,9,9,6,17],
                    'date_y' : [9,17,50,60,67],
                            })

data_extract = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['AA', 'BB'],
                    'date' : ['03/02/2015', '01/02/2015']
                            })


df1_bis = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['AA', 'AA','AA'],
                    'date' : ['01/02/2015','03/02/2015','08/02/2015'],
                    'value' :  [6,'something',7],
                    'date_y' : [32,34 ,39]
                            })

df2_bis = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['BB', 'BB','BB', 'BB','BB'],
                    'date' : ['17/01/2015', '01/02/2015','19/02/2015', '01/03/2015','08/03/2015'],
                    'value' :  [9,'something',9,6,17],
                    'date_y' : [17,32, 50,60,67],
                            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard question ..I break down the steps.

```
merge_asof, bffil, dropna, concat,sort_values,reindex,MultiIndex,groupby, interpolate
```

---

*1st part*

clear the data , convert the date to `datetime` format , and sort the value(`sort_values`) , for future merge

```
df1.date=pd.to_datetime(df1.date,dayfirst=True)
data_extract.date=pd.to_datetime(data_extract.date,dayfirst=True)
df2.date=pd.to_datetime(df2.date,dayfirst=True)
data_extract=data_extract.assign(key=1).sort_values('date')
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values('date')
```

---

*2nd part*

Using `merge_asof` get the merge with your condition , how it work check`[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
Yourdf=pd.merge_asof(df,data_extract,on='date',by='id',allow_exact_matches=False)
```

---

*3rd part*

Modify the result dataframe ,drop those dates are smaller than the target date, notice I am using `limit` 1 in `ffill` since you need keep the first less row before the date

```
Yourdf['key']=Yourdf.groupby('id').key.bfill(limit=1)

Yourdf=Yourdf.dropna(subset=['key'])
Yourdf=pd.concat([Yourdf,data_extract],sort=False)
```

---

*4th part*

Using `interpolate` with `groupby` fill the value missing in the `date_y`, for the value from `data_extract`

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Yourdf.id,Yourdf.date])
Yourdf['date_y']=Yourdf.groupby('id').apply(lambda x : x.set_index('date').date_y.interpolate('index')).reindex(idx).values

Yourdf['value'].fillna('something',inplace=True)

Yourdf.sort_values(['id','date'],inplace=True)


Yourdf.drop('key',1,inplace=True)
```

---

*5th*

```
#check the result 
Yourdf
Out[1036]: 
   id       date      value  date_y
5  AA 2015-02-01          6    32.0
0  AA 2015-02-03  something    34.0
6  AA 2015-02-08          7    39.0
3  BB 2015-01-17          9    17.0
1  BB 2015-02-01  something    32.0
7  BB 2015-02-19          9    50.0
8  BB 2015-03-01          6    60.0
9  BB 2015-03-08         17    67.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one question in my example df1, df2, and data_extract have a column with the same name 'date' but in my script they have different names. df1 and df2 have a column named 'date_observed' and data_extract's date column  is named 'date_event'. I was able to overcome this issue during the merge ```Yourdf=pd.merge_asof(right_on='date_event',left_on='date_observed')``` but it is problematic because I have my dates in two different columns and a bunch of NaT. An easy solution would be to rename the columns but if it is possible to do otherwise that would be useful.

Comment: @JulienAzhar yes, you can rename them , since you mentioned two dfshave the same structure

Comment: Nothing is hard for you ;)

Comment: @Wen-Ben he's right your answer has been helpful for a beginner! I have an issue ```idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Yourdf.id,Yourdf.date])```raises the error ```cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!``` I think this is caused by the fact that in some cases my dataframes (df1, df2, etc) and data_extract have a date in common. For example if I have  ```data_extract = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['BB'], 'date' : ['19/02/2015'] })``` at the I would have ```Yourdf = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['BB', 'BB','BB'],  'date' : ['19/02/2015', '01/03/2015','08/03/2015'],'value' :  [9,6,17, 'date_y' : [50,60,67]})```

Comment: @JulienAzhar I think you have duplicated date in df1 or df2 check it:-)